# Query on string based wildcard shiro permission

Tags: java, shiro

I am storing my permissions in the wildcard string format for e.g. (Menu:dashboard,Report:first etc). I have a separate report table which stores all reports and its attributes. But there is no foreign key relation between report and permission table. (If I store permissions in relational way, this can be done)

Now I have to retrieve all reports users are entitled to for displaying on UI. 
One way is to query all reports and then filter based on the Subject's allowable permissions. But I just want to know the best practice, how other people in this group handle this situation.

EDIT

Anyone has any opinion on this or if they can share how they are managing permissions.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its better instead of storing Menu:dashboard,Report:first in database store individual permissions so as to query them easily and also when in case you have to implement a logic like hasanypermission(p1,p2...) it will not misbehave.

I store my all permissions in a table mstpermission that is having app lermissions that are possible for the system
and 
appermission where roles are mapped to permissions

```
MSTPERMISSION
PERMID  VARCHAR2(20 )
STATUS  NUMBER(1,0)
PERMDESC    VARCHAR2(100)
```

has data like

```
*   1   All Permissions
entry   1   All Entries
entry:create    1   Create Entries
entry:edit  1   Edit/Delete Entries
reports 1   All Reports
reports:dashboard   1   DashBoard
reports:general 1   General Report


APPPERMISSION
PERMID  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
ROLEID  VARCHAR2(3 BYTE)
```

has entries like

```
*   00
entry:create    01
entry:edit  01
reports:general 01
appt    02
entry:edit  02
reports:general 02
```

Comment: Don't you think by this way , we are ignoring the power full wildcard permission check. For e.g. checking if user has permission on a particular instance of printer which can be done using printer:*:123.

Comment: i know but when I tried to implement that in actual scenario using that way was going more troublesome than to be easy

Comment: Thanks @dev in that case I would prefer having a table of resource with all resources and many to many relation with permission table.